# Searching for a good gaming-headset (gaming and music)

Tags: gaming, headphones, headset, music

I'm searching for a good **headset** for gaming and hearing music. And I don't know which headsets are good and which aren't.

To specify my question, I'm searching for a headset, that

- is good for gaming / hearing music (good sound quality)
- costs between 100€ and 200€
- is well-made (lasts for a long time)
- supports 600ohm soundcard
- is made out of metal (e.g. aluminium) [not really needed if it's well-made]
- has a good microphone for recording + teamspeak

I hope somebody knows something that fits these "requirements". If possible, the headset can also have

- a controller
- led lights
- a black and red color scheme

I have already taken a look at some things and thought about buying a **beyerdynamics MMX 300** but this costs too much and is literally just a headset with a microphone. Another headset I thought would be good is an **Astro a40** but this would be a little bit too expensive.

> If you think I can't get everything I want with this budget, let me know.

Answer (score 5):

Not so easy to find Gaming headset with 600ohm. I know the Sennheiser HMD 26-II-600-X3K1 but it's out of your range.

600ohm is better but it doesn't mean that you cannot use lower impedence headset (http://www.cnet.com/news/headphone-buyers-heres-what-you-need-to-know-about-low-vs-high-impedance-models/)

Considering this, going for the HyperX Cloud Revolver might be a good solution because:

- In your price range (130€)
- Good reviews (espcially on sound and mic)
- Steel and well made
- LEDs
- Controller
- Black and red

Comment: This thing looks great! Don't know where the LEDs are but they are irrelevant. I think I might go for this one if I don't find anything else :)

Comment: I think that the LEDs are behind the red logo on both sides ;)